# Is there a ``Ladner's Theorem" for the PH-vs-PSPACE scenario?

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity, model-theory, formal-languages

Like a statement of the kind, ``If the Polynomial Hierarchy (PH) $\neq$ PSPACE then there exists $L \in PSPACE \backslash PH$ which is not PSPACE-complete"?

Or is there something else that states that this is impossible?

Comment: Yes, see http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/7640 . Also http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/863 is relevant.